# Insertion sort in descending order in C++

Tags: c++

I am facing an issue with insertion sort function. While I am trying to make the votes and names to print in descending order. The votes seem to work but the name is printing in ascending order instead of descending order. After I plug in a b c d e f for the names and 5 4 3 2 1 for the votes, it looks like this:

```
Please input the canditate 1 name:
a
Please input the canditate 1 votes:
1
Please input the canditate 2 name:
b
Please input the canditate 2 votes:
2
Please input the canditate 3 name:
c
Please input the canditate 3 votes:
3
Please input the canditate 4 name:
d
Please input the canditate 4 votes:
4
Please input the canditate 5 name:
e
Please input the canditate 5 votes:
5
Candidate               Votes Received          % of Total Votes
a                       5                       33.33
b                       4                       26.67
c                       3                       20.00
d                       2                       13.33
e                       1                       6.67
Total                   15
The winner of the elections is a.
Program ended with exit code: 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The candidate need to be e d c b a instead of a b c d e.
This is my code below. Any help will be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

void insertionSort(double votes[], string name[], double len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++)
    {
        int j = i + 1;
        double temp = votes[j];
        while (j > 0 && temp > votes[j - 1]) 
            {
                    votes[j] = votes[j - 1];
                    j--;
                    votes[j] = temp;
            }
        string temp2 = name[j];
        while (j > 0 && temp2 > name[j - 1])
          {
              name[j] = name[j - 1];
              j--;
              name[j] = temp2;
          }
    }


}
int main()
{
    //Declaring variables 
    string *name;
    double *votes;
    double *percentage;
    double total = 0;
    int max = 0;

    name = new string[5];
    votes = new double[5];
    percentage = new double[5];
    //for condition for user to input Canditate names and the votes received 
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please input the canditate " << i + 1 << " " << "name: " << endl;
        cin >> name[i];
        cout << "Please input the canditate " << i + 1 << " " << "votes: " << endl;
        cin >> votes[i];
        total = total + votes[i];

    }
    //Q1 or Q2
    //selectionSort(votes, name, 5);
    insertionSort(votes, name, 5);

    //printing out the Canditate, voters received, and % of total votes 
    cout << "Candidate" << "\t\t" << "Votes Received" << "\t\t" << "% of Total Votes" << endl;
    //for loop in order to find % of total votes, winner of election
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (votes[i]>votes[max])
            max = i;
        cout << name[i] << "\t\t\t" << fixed << setprecision(0) << votes[i] << "\t\t\t" << fixed << setprecision(2) << (votes[i] * 100 / total) << endl;

    }
    //printing out the total and winner of the election 
    cout << "Total" << "\t\t\t" << fixed << setprecision(0) << total << endl;
    cout << "The winner of the elections is " << name[max] << "." << endl;

    delete[]name;
    delete[]votes;

    cout << "Program ended with exit code: 0" << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Recommendation: remove the user input and hardcode a set of values into the arrays. This way you are 1. saving time typing the same crap in over and over. 2. always testing the same input uncorrupted by typos. 3. Presenting your exact test case to those of us out here in the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make data consistnt, ie keep it together in struct, try:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

/*void selectionSort(double votes[], string name[], double len)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < len-1; i++)

    {
        double max = (int)i;


        for (int j = i+1; j < len; j++)
        {

            if (votes[j]>votes[(int)max])
            {
                double temp = votes[i];
                votes[i] = votes[j];
                votes[j] = temp;

                string temp2 = name[i];
                name[i] = name[j];
                name[j] = temp2;
            }

        }
    }
}*/

struct candidate{
    string *name;
    double votes;
    double percentage;
};

void insertionSort( candidate candidates[], double len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++)
    {
        int j = i + 1;
        candidate tmp = candidates[i];
        while (j > 0 && tmp.votes > candidates[j-1].votes)
            {
                    candidates[j] = candidates[j - 1];
                    j--;
                    candidates[j] = tmp;
            }
    }

}
int main()
{
    //Declaring variables
candidate candidates[5];
    double total = 0;
    int max = 0;

    //for condition for user to input Canditate names and the votes received
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = new string;
        cout << "Please input the canditate " << i + 1 << " " << "name: " << endl;
        cin >> *(candidates[i].name);
        cout << "Please input the canditate " << i + 1 << " " << "votes: " << endl;
        cin >> candidates[i].votes;
        total = total + candidates[i].votes;

    }
    //Q1 or Q2
    //selectionSort(candidates, 5);
    insertionSort(candidates, 5);

    //printing out the Canditate, voters received, and % of total votes
    cout << "Candidate" << "\t\t" << "Votes Received" << "\t\t" << "% of Total Votes" << endl;
    //for loop in order to find % of total votes, winner of election
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << *(candidates[i].name) << "\t\t\t" << fixed << setprecision(0) << candidates[i].votes << "\t\t\t" << fixed << setprecision(2) << (candidates[i].votes * 100 / total) << endl;

    }
    //printing out the total and winner of the election
    cout << "Total" << "\t\t\t" << fixed << setprecision(0) << total << endl;
    cout << "The winner of the elections is " << *(candidates[0].name) << "." << endl;

    for(int i=0; i<5; ++i)
     delete candidates[i].name;

    cout << "Program ended with exit code: 0" << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: It did not work, with this way they are printing out in ascending order instead of descending order. is there a way i can change it without changing my main function?

Comment: Try now all you need to change sign in "tmp.votes > candidates[j-1].votes", i have already changed it